# Filtro y obtención MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener un `array` con los datos de la columna `"codigo"` de aquellos registros que tengan un `codigopostal = 1001`

Para ello con un *rest service* hago un `post`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez lo tengo, necesito extraer el primer parámetro del `array` e introducirlo en una variable para luego utilizarlo en la construcción de un `URI` para la obtención de un `XML` en un servidor externo.

Para construir este `URI` por ejemplo:

```
"http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_01059.xml"
```

Hago esto:

```
"http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_" + "0" + "codigo" + ".xml"
```

**El problema es que no añade "codigo".**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Detallo a continuación el código:

```
<?php

require_once 'login_mysql.php';

if(isset($_POST['postCode']) && !empty($_POST['postCode'])){

$sql = "SELECT alava.codigo FROM alava WHERE alava.codigopostal = '$postCode'";


if (mysqli_connect_error()){
echo 'Error de Conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
exit();
}

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$r){
echo 'No se pudo hacer la consulta: ' . mysqli_error($con);
echo json_encode("Registro inexistente");
exit();
}

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

   //Pushing name and id in the blank array created
    array_push($result,array(
    "codigo"=>$row['codigo']

    ));
  $codigo = array_values($result)[0];
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$output_result));

// Close mysql connection
mysqli_close($con);

  }else{
 echo "Operacion fallida";
  }

 $json_object = json_decode( json_encode(array('result'=>$result)) );


 $localidad = "$codigo";
 $cadena1 = "http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_";
 $cadena2 = "$localidad";
 $cadena3 = ".xml";
 $prefijo = "0";
 $url=$cadena1 . $prefijo . $cadena2 . $cadena3 ;


 $texto = file_get_contents($url);
 $texto = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $texto);
 $texto = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $texto));
 $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($texto);
 $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
 echo $json;

return $json;
```

Comment: Fijate que `result = null` lo que significa que posiblemente no está entrando en el `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))` o tal vez `$row['codigo']` esté retornando un `NULL`; fijate si el nombre de campo es `codigo`, o tal vez sea `Codigo`, porque `mysqli_fech_array()` devuelve *[los nombres de los campos sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)*.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el problema se encuentra exactamente donde dices, pero no consigo identificar o aislar el problema, lo miro y parece correcto. "codigo" está en la tabla en minúscula. Aparentemente parece bien formulado...

Comment: Parece que falta la conexión `$con = mysqli_connect("servidor", "nombre de usuario", "contraseña", "base de datos");`

Comment: El Rest Service me indica que la conexión fue exitosa "Status:
200: OK
Loading time: 341 ms". Lo he comprobado con otro *.php que requiere conexión y la establecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paso a responder a mi propia pregunta. He hecho varias pruebas con diferentes estructuras y esta es la que me resulta más clara y al mismo tiempo funciona correctamente después de probarla en el Web Service.

Primero hago una solicitud con sintaxis correcta a la tabla prerguntando por todos los elementos que tienen como index "cosigopostal" recibido por POST.

```
if(isset($_POST['postCode']) && !empty($_POST['postCode'])){
$postCode = $_POST['postCode'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_alava WHERE wp_alava.codigopostal = '$postCode'";
```

Una vez hecho esto, introducimos los datos en un array. Debido a que se pueden recibir desde uno a varios parámetros (si se reciben varios son repetidos) y a que no sabemos cuantos se reciben, seleccionamos el primero y desechamos el resto.

```
//creating a blank array
 $result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){


 array_push($result,array(
//Pushing codigo in the blank array created
        "codigo"=>$row['codigo']
    ));
}

//Displaying the array in json format
 $codigo_poblacion = json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

 $primer_codigo_encontrado = json_decode($codigo_poblacion);

 $primer_codigo_encontrado->result[0]->codigo;
 $codigo_poblacion_aemet = $primer_codigo_encontrado->result[0]->codigo;
```

Ahora, nos interesa pasarlo a Json pues lo vamos a utilizar posteriormente en una APP y este formato nos resulta más cómodo. En la web de AEMET nos dan las predicciones en formato XML.

```
$cadena1 = "http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_";
$cadena3 = ".xml";
$prefijo = "0";
$url=$cadena1 . $prefijo . $codigo_poblacion_aemet . $cadena3 ;


$texto = file_get_contents($url);
$texto = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $texto);
$texto = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $texto));
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($texto);
$json = json_encode($simpleXml);
echo $json;

return $json;
```

Bueno, aquí hay una pequeñá "API" para poder extraer datos creando un URI de una fuente de "OPENDATA" correspondiente a AEMET. En dicha web no dan sus propios API con URIS con lo que se deben construir.
saludos